# ¿Cómo puedo relacionar registros de una misma tabla para afectarlos a ambos en una consulta?

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo un problema en una parte de un sistema de venta e inventario, ya que hay productos que se hacen de una misma materia prima *(ej. carne a la plancha y picada de carne)*. Pasa más o menos lo siguiente:
Quiero que cuando venda el uno o el otro producto se descuente de ambos. El siguiente es más o menos el código que estoy manejando en php:

```
<?php
//selección de los platos  
   try {
        require_once('../sistema/conexion.php');
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM platos WHERE estado='disponible' OR cantidad = NULL AND cantidad != 0 ORDER BY nombre"; 
        $plato = $conn->query($sql);
   } catch (Exception $e) {
         $error = $e->getMessage();
   } 
  ?>
```

La tabla platos tiene los siguientes datos:
id = int(11) AUTO_INCREMENT
nombre = varchar(100)
precio = varchar(25)
cantidad = int(11)
estado = varchar(50)
Básicamente tengo un select con cada uno de los platos, así:

```
    <input type="number" id="cantidad" name="cantidad">
    <select id="platos" name="platos">
    <?php while($platos = $plato->fetch_assoc() ) { ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $platos['nombre']; ?>"> echo $platos['cantidad'];</option>
<?php } ?>
//Para mostrar el nombre y la cantidad
```

Finalmente, después del pedido se ejecuta lo siguiente para descontar la cantidad de productos vendidos:

```
<?php
$cant = $_POST['cantidad'];
$plato = $_POST['platos'];
$sql = "UPDATE platos SET cantidad = cantidad - {$cant} WHERE nombre = '{$plato}'; ";
$descontar= $conn->query($sql);
?>
```

Lo que sucede con esto último es que cada producto se descuenta satisfactoriamente, pero de manera individual.
Quiero que así como el ejemplo de la carne lo pueda hacer con varios productos más, pero no he encontrado la manera de hacerlo.
**Muchas gracias por la ayuda que me puedan brindar**

Comment: No entiendo muy bien tu duda. ¿Dices que sólo funciona cuando el plato se llama `carne` o ...? Por otra parte, no me queda claro que tu modelo de datos sea el más idóneo. Quizá deberías manejar otra tabla que lleve el control de cada producto y su existencia. La columna `cantidad` podría ser un elemento extraño en la tabla `plato` además no es bueno estar constantemente actualizando esa tabla (pienso por ejemplo de cara a los índices y demás).

Comment: @A.Cedano El Update toma el nombre exacto del producto seleccionado y allí se le resta la cantidad vendida.
Tomando lo de la carne; hay varios productos de carne (carne a la plancha y picada de carne), por lo que cuando seleccione carne a la plancha me descontará solo de esa y no de la picada. Mi idea era, que de alguna manera, se pudiera descontar de ambos.
Tu idea de crear una tabla y relacionarla es muy buena (no sé porqué no se me había ocurrido), pero te agradecería demasiado si puedes decirme más o menos cómo tú pretendrías hacerlo para hacerme una idea y poder realizarlo

Comment: La idea es muy simple. Cuando creas una aplicación considera los componentes de la misma como entidades de la vida real. Separa entidades y relaciona cuando se requiera. Otra cosa que ayuda es llamar a cada cosa por su nombre. Si hablamos de `plato` por ejemplo ya estamos ante una confusión, porque un plato tiene muchas cosas. O sea, para referirte a cosas como `carne, pescado, cebolla` habría que hablar mejor de `producto` y no de plato... un plato sería una combinación de varios productos. Si partimos de ahí, con la ideas claras, entonces se puede empezar a diseñar un modelo de datos ...

Comment: ... basado en la realidad. Hablaríamos entonces de una tabla `producto` donde iría `carne, pescado, tomate, cebolla` etc. En esa tabla iría solamente lo que es propio de un producto, o sea, lo que todo producto tiene en sí mismo. Cada fila de esa tabla va a tener un  `ID` que la va a identificar de forma única y que servirá para relacionar ese producto con cualquier otra tabla del modelo de datos.

Comment: ... a partir de ahí puedes crear por ejemplo una entidad `plato`, porque estás haciendo una app para un restaurante. En ese tabla `plato` cada fila tendrá un `id` también que la va a identificar. Y podría tener varias entidades de la tabla `producto`. Por ejemplo, un plato que es *pescado a la plancha con cebolla*, tendría dos `ids` de la tabla `producto`, el del producto `pescado`  y el del producto `cebolla`.

Comment: A lo mejor crees que te estoy complicando la vida de este modo. Pues no, es todo lo contrario. Estamos montando algo lógico, porque así funcionan las cosas en la realidad. Y esto que puede parecer complejo es mucho más fácil de mantener o de obtener cualquier información. En una app los requerimientos pueden ser del tipo: *¿cuántos kilos de cebolla hay en existencia para el mes febrero?*  ... si tienes mezclada la cebolla, el tomate y la carne, te quiero ver cómo cumples con ese requerimiento. Y lo peor es que cuando diseñas algo hay requerimientos que no están y que vienen luego, cuando la

Comment: ...tabla tiene millones de registros. Volviendo a los platos, puedes tener en esa tabla varias filas que serían todos los platos que hay en ese restaurante. Si  interesa llevar un control de cuántos platos quedan, abres una relación entre la tabla `plato` y una tabla que haría de inventario. En esa tabla de inventario pones el `id` de cada plato y la cantidad total, y es de esa tabla desde la cual vas a ir descontando en la medida en que se vaya pidiendo un determinado plato. He escrito demasiado, no sé si captas el núcleo de la cuestión. La clave es simple: diseñar en base a la realidad.

Comment: Además en la bases de datos hay algo que se llama `TRIGGER`, son eventos que programas para que se disparen ante ciertas acciones. Si tienes bien ordenado el modelo de datos puedes luego tener un `TRIGGER` que se dispare cada vez que alguien pide un plato (un `INSERT` en la tabla `pedido`)  y que descuente la cantidad de platos que se pidieron de la totalidad de los platos que hay en `inventario`. Nada más con eso te puedes dar cuenta de las enormes ventajas de un modelo de datos bien diseñado. Aparte de que no tendrás redundancia, todo irá más rápido por los índices, etc.